# How do you pass a const or static parameter to a function?

Tags: rust

How do you pass a const or static to a function in Rust?

Why do these not work?:

```
const COUNT: i32 = 5;

fn main() {
let repeated = "*".repeat(COUNT);
println!("Repeated Value: {}", repeated);
}
```

And

```
static COUNT: i32 = 5;

fn main() {
    let repeated = "*".repeat(COUNT);
    println!("Repeated Value: {}", repeated);
}
```

They return:

```
mismatched types
expected `usize`, found `i32`
```

But these work fine?:

```
fn main() {
    let repeated = "*".repeat(5);
    println!("Repeated Value: {}", repeated);
}
```

And

```
fn main() {
    let count = 5;
    let repeated = "*".repeat(count);
    println!("Repeated Value: {}", repeated);
}
```

Surely `const` works the same way as `5`? Both should be type i32

```
= "*".repeat(COUNT)
```

vs

```
= "*".repeat(5)
```

And similarly shouldn't 'static' work like 'let'? What am I missing here? How do you use a const as a parameter to a function call?

Comment: You would get the same error if you specified the type like you do for `const` or `static`: `let count: i32 = 5;`

Comment: Interesting. So why does .repeat(5) work?

Answer (score 7):

It has nothing to do with the definition of `COUNT`. `repeat` takes a `usize`, not a `u32`.

You either need to define `COUNT` as a usize

```
const COUNT: usize = 5;
```

Or convert `COUNT` to a `usize` when you call `repeat`

```
let repeated = "*".repeat(COUNT as usize);
```

Comment: This works great. So final question... whys does .repeat(5) work? Does rust automatically cast the 5 into usize. I assume it is created as type i32 as the default int type.

Comment: Yes when 5 is used as is it is coerced into a usize.

Comment: @toconn Yes the `5` literal is being treated as a `usize`. If it diddnt it would have to do stuff
`const COUNT: usize = 5 as usize;` and also have the side effects of meaning all literals being a fixed size. e.g. if all `5` literals where `u32`, you would never be able to assign a max value of a `u64` with a literal.

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate the answers!

Comment: @AhmedMasud To be precise, the literal is _coerced_ to `usize`, but rather _inferred_ to be `usize`. This is the same effect as if you would write `5_usize`. I'm not aware of any practical difference, however.

Comment: Which is why you will sometimes see error messages which refer to the type of a value as `{integer}` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=493393edf40ede2440dd01a4ed21d37b)) when the compiler hasn't gone far enough in the type inference to determine a concrete type.